# Retrying with different port number

Tags: arrays, ruby, ip, port

I have a program that will ping an IP address, then log the IP to a file if it pings successfully:

```
Invalid IP: 128.201.166.30
Proxy created: 66.25.173.128:80
Invalid IP: 225.195.111.59
Invalid IP: 249.133.221.70
Invalid IP: 40.21.11.99
Invalid IP: 201.27.136.108
Invalid IP: 152.77.109.45
Invalid IP: 120.76.159.122
Invalid IP: 108.244.67.42
Invalid IP: 73.231.16.193
Proxy created: 146.134.102.95:3128
Invalid IP: 133.216.1.59
Proxy created: 118.75.196.75:3128
```

Now what I would like to do is have the "good" IP address use each port in the following array: `port = %w(80 3128 8080 8090 8888 8898 9999)`, for example:

```
Proxy created: 66.25.173.128:80
Proxy created: 66.25.173.128:3128
Proxy created: 66.25.173.128:8080
Proxy created: 66.25.173.128:8090
Proxy created: 66.25.173.128:8888
Proxy created: 66.25.173.128:8898
Proxy created: 66.25.173.128:9999
#Creates an IP with a port extension with each port number
```

I think I have a general idea on how I could do this:

```
File.open("example.txt", "a+"){
  |s| s.puts("#{ip}:#{port[0]}", 
             "#{ip}:#{port[1]}",
             "#{ip}:#{port[2]}"
             #etc...
                              )}
```

I'm not entirely sure if that would work the way I'm expecting it to though, and even if it does, I'm 100% sure there's a better way to do, any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Source:

```
require 'colored'
require 'timeout'

def create_possibles
  port = %w(80 3128 8080 8090 8888 8898 9999).each do |port|
    10.times do 
      ip = Array.new(4){rand(256)}.join('.')
      Timeout::timeout(5) do
        ping = `ping -n 1 #{ip}` 
        if ping =~ /Received = 1/ 
          proxy = "#{ip}:#{port}"
          puts "Proxy created: #{proxy}".green.bold
          File.open("proxies.txt", "a+") {|s| s.puts(proxy)}
        else
          puts "Invalid IP: #{ip}".red.bold
          next
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

create_possibles
```

---

**EDIT:**

I attempted my general idea of how to do this:

```
require 'colored'
require 'timeout'

def create_possibles
  w%(80 3128 8080 8090 8888 8898 9999).each do |port|
    1.times do 
      ip = Array.new(4){rand(256)}.join('.')
      Timeout::timeout(5) do
        ping = `ping -n 1 #{ip}` 
        if ping =~ /Received = 1/ 
#          proxy = "#{ip}:#{port}"           
          puts "[SUCCESS]Proxy created for IP: #{ip}".green.bold
          File.open("proxies.txt", "a+") {|s| s.puts("#{ip}:#{port[0]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{port[1]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{port[2]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{port[3]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{port[4]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{port[5]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{port[6]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{port[7]}")}
        else
          puts "[ERROR]IP failed to ping: #{ip}".red.bold
          next
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

create_possibles
```

When run:

```
[ERROR]IP failed to ping: 185.105.73.104
[ERROR]IP failed to ping: 93.182.117.11
[ERROR]IP failed to ping: 112.210.73.187
[ERROR]IP failed to ping: 111.109.127.178
[SUCCESS]Proxy created for IP: 201.153.205.131
[ERROR]IP failed to ping: 128.236.57.123
[ERROR]IP failed to ping: 248.84.17.31
```

It ends up outputting information that looks like this:

```
201.153.205.131:0
201.153.205.131:0
201.153.205.131:0
201.153.205.131:1
201.153.205.131:1
201.153.205.131:1
201.153.205.131:0
201.153.205.131:1
```

Comment: looks good to me ... what is the problem? are you getting an error?

Comment: @maxpleaner No I just wasn't 100% sure if it would work, so the `#{port[0]}`;`#{port[1]}` etc.. Will work the way I expect it to?

Comment: why don't you try it and see? It looks like you're making a pentesting app so I understand the desire to not run bad code, but you're always going to have to run your code to see if it works. And then you have to learn how to understand errors.

Comment: May want to check to see if your randomly generated IP address is valid while you are at it.  http://sqa.fyicenter.com/Online_Test_Tools/IP_Address_Format_Validator.php

Comment: @maxpleaner Yes I am, I did try it, I'll edit the question with the results.

Comment: @JLB That's what the ping is for, if it doesn't ping, it's probably not going to anytime soon.

Comment: The output of your last example makes it clear that `port` is the string `"8080"`, not an array. That doesn't match your other code.

Comment: @Jordan I don't understand, how can `port` be a string if it's clearly initiated as an array?

Comment: Your last example doesn't show the code that initializes `port`, so I can't say. But `"8"`, `"0"`, `"8"`, `"0"`, `nil`, `nil`, etc. is exactly what you'd expect to get if `port` was the string `"8080"`.

Comment: @Jordan One second, I'll put the code

Comment: @Jordan Fixed, I hope this clarifies what I mean

Comment: Your port variable isn't an array, it's a string.

Comment: do this:  ports = %w(80 3128 8080 8090 8888 8898 9999)

Comment: then ports.each do |port|

Comment: and change your port puts to ports[0], ports[1], etc

Comment: @JLB That produces the same result: `67.141.139.104:9`;
`67.141.139.104:9`;
`67.141.139.104:9`;
`67.141.139.104:9`;
`67.141.139.104:`;
`67.141.139.104:`;
`67.141.139.104:`;
`67.141.139.104:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The problem had to do with the `.each do |ports|`;

If I take that out like this:

```
require 'colored'
require 'timeout'

def create_possibles
  ports = %w(80 3128 8080 8090 8888 8898 9999)
    5.times do 
      ip = Array.new(4){rand(256)}.join('.')
      Timeout::timeout(5) do
        ping = `ping -n 1 #{ip}` 
        if ping =~ /Received = 1/ 
#          proxy = "#{ip}:#{port}"           
          puts "[SUCCESS]Proxy created for IP: #{ip}".green.bold
          File.open("proxies.txt", "a+") {|s| s.puts("#{ip}:#{ports[0]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[1]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[2]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[3]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[4]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[5]}",
                                                     "#{ip}:#{ports[6]}")}
        else
          puts "[ERROR]IP failed to ping: #{ip}".red.bold
          next
        end
      end
    end
  end

create_possibles
```

Then run it as is, it will output:

```
[ERROR]IP failed to ping: 111.20.77.200
[SUCCESS]Proxy created for IP: 217.252.149.35
[ERROR]IP failed to ping: 49.214.128.47
[ERROR]IP failed to ping: 116.101.28.115
[ERROR]IP failed to ping: 75.49.120.242
```

And will log:

```
217.252.149.35:80
217.252.149.35:3128
217.252.149.35:8080
217.252.149.35:8090
217.252.149.35:8888
217.252.149.35:8898
217.252.149.35:9999
```